# javascript window.open not following setInterval parameters?

Tags: javascript, popup, setinterval, onload, clearinterval

I have a very oddly specific project which requires a number of photos to be opened in multiple window popups. (I understand the usability of this, please bypass that for the moment.)

I am running the following script on body load, which works *somewhat* so far:

```
// Popup window code
function runPopups() {
  popupWin1 = setInterval(
    function() {
      window.open('assets/pic1.jpg', '_blank', 'width=490,height=300,left=-1000,top=-1000')
    }, 3000);
  //clearInterval(popupWin1);

  popupWin2 = setInterval(
    function() {
      window.open('assets/pic2.jpg', '_blank', 'width=600,height=500,left=0,top=0')
    }, 3000);
  //clearInterval(popupWin2);
}
```

It actually seems to sort of load them once but then keeps looping back through.  When I add the `clearInterval` parameter, it breaks the script altogether.  I'm so close but not sure what I'm doing wrong as javascript is not my main understanding.  I feel like I'm either missing a loop somehow or maybe I need to put it into a whole different function?

Ideally, I want each photo to pop up in a random spot on the screen, with a varied delayed time - bonus if each one can be faster and faster.  I will have about 10-20 pics to pop up.  Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a for loop with `setTimeout` to schedule each popup individually. If each popup has a different name and parameters, you can store that in an array and loop through it with a for loop.

```js
const popups = [
  {
    url: 'assets/pic1.jpg',
    params: 'width=490,height=300,left=-1000,top=-1000',
  },
  {
    url: 'assets/pic2.jpg',
    params: 'width=600,height=500,left=0,top=0',
  },
  // Add the rest here
];

function runPopups() {
  for (let i = 0; i < popups.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(
      () => window.open(popups[i].url, '_blank', popups[i].params),
      (i + 1) * 3000
    );
  }
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-2rgp5n?file=index.ts

You're scheduling the first one to popup after 3 seconds, the second after 6 seconds, the third after 9 seconds, etc. If you want the first to appear immediately just remove the `+ 1`.

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly!!!  Is there a way to change the ```(i + 1) * 3000``` to be increasingly faster?  For example if the first one runs at 3 seconds, the next one runs at 5 instead of 6, and so on.  If not, this works just fine.

Comment: something like `(i+1) * 3000 - Math.max(3000, i*200)` would reduce the 3 second step by 200ms each iteration. Of course you can play with the calculation however you want. It may be easier to calculate your timeout value on multiple lines before calling `setTimeout` with your final value.

Comment: @RodeoRamsey typo: should be `Math.min` not `Math.max` oops!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
// Popup window code
const assets = [{
  url: 'assets/pic1.jpg',
  settings: 'width=490,height=300,left=-1000,top=-1000'
}, {
  url: 'assets/pic2.jpg',
  settings: 'width=600,height=500,left=0,top=0'
}]
const runPopups = () => {
  for (i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
    window.open(assets[i].url, '_blank', assets[i].settings);
  }
};
runPopups();
setInterval(runPopups, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

use setTimeout instead of setInterval, because setInterval means to open popup after every 3 secs that's why it is opening again and again

```
// Popup window code
function runPopups() {
  window.open('assets/pic1.jpg', '_blank', 'width=490,height=300,left=-1000,top=-1000')
  setTimeout(function() {
      window.open('assets/pic2.jpg', '_blank', 'width=600,height=500,left=0,top=0')
    }, 3000);
  //clearInterval(popupWin2);
}
```

Comment: I want to run it every 3 seconds (or at least have all the windows popped open in order every 3 seconds until done), so that's why I used setInterval.  Changing it to setTimeout causes only the first image to open.